# Есть ли возможность сделать код практичнее и короче?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Задание на определение самой правой цифры бинарной записи числа

```
def binar():
    b=int(input())
    b=bin(b)
    num=[]
    num=b.split
    ln=len(b)
    g=int(b[ln-1])

    if g==1:
        print ("Yes")
    elif g==0:
        print ("No")

a=int(input())
for i in range(a):
    binar()
```

[Код в виде изображения из оригинала вопроса](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKztz.png)

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») **должны включать** желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный **код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Проблем нет, код работает, вопрос в том, можно ли сделать его короче. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Код должен быть приведен прямо в вопросе, а не на сторонних ресурсах, и уж точно не картинками

Comment: Так же ознакомьтесь с правилами для инспекции кода: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/инспекция-кода/info

Comment: Вторая часть вопроса была задана именно для решения этой проблемы. (Я спросил, как сделать лучше, а вы обвиняете, что не делаю лучше. В чем смысл?)

Comment: def binar():
 b=int(input())
 b=bin(b)
 num=[]
 num=b.split
 ln=len(b)
 g=int(b[ln-1])

 
 if g==1:
  print ("Yes")
 elif g==0: print ("No")


a=int(input())
for i in range(a):
 binar()
Вот код, но если я пытаюсь его вставить в вопросе, а не в комментариях, выдаёт ошибку о редактировании кода под стандарт сайта (2 фотография в вопросе). Я с радостью буду соблюдать правила сайта, но не понимаю как

Comment: @Pasha, я поправил вам вопрос. На будущее - в скриншоте кода я у вас в редакторе вижу кнопку Tab. Если эта кнопка работает как я думаю, то нужно выделить весь код, нажать таб (перед всеми строками добавится отступ). Копируете код, вставляете в вопрос, сохраняете - он будет отформатирован. В мобильной версии stackoverflow, насколько я вижу, отсутствует кнопка форматирования.

Comment: @insolor , спасибо, что поправили вопрос. На скриншоте tab делает отступ в 1 строчке. Вообще, если я правильно понимаю, то копируя из приложения, вставляется сплошной текст. Так что моя проблема всё ещё не решена :(

Comment: @Pasha, попробуйте использовать с телефона полную версию сайта (переключение на нее в самом низу страницы), тогда редактор вопроса будет выглядеть так: [скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqhey.png). Вставляете код, выделяете, нажимаете кнопку с фигурными скобками.

Answer (score 4):

Если Вам нужно определить самый младший разряд числа, то на мой взгляд, самый простой способ, это выяснить чётность числа. Очевидно, что у всех чётных чисел самый младший разряд 0, а у нечётных - 1

```
a=int(input())
if a % 2 == 1: # нечётное
    print("Yes")
else: # чётное
    print("No")
```

Comment: Еще короче: `print("Yes" if a % 2 else "No")`

Comment: print("yes" if a%==1 else "no")   ?

Comment: @Pasha, это `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, а я про `print("Yes" if a % 2 else "No")`, можно и `print("Yes" if a % 2 == 1 else "No")`, но это не короче :)

Comment: @Pasha вааще в одну строку `print("Yes" if int(input()) % 2 else "No")`

Answer (score 4):

Без всяких проверок if:

```
num = 2
print("This number is"+" not"*(num&1)+" odd")
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `num=b.split` - это не вызов метода `split`, это запись самого метода в переменную `num`. Для вызова функции, метода или объекта с возможностью вызова ("callable") нужны круглые скобки: `num = b.split()`. Будьте внимательны, отсутствие скобок при вызове может привести ошибкам. У вас ошибка не возникает из-за того что это значение потом никак не используется (см. пункт 2).
2. [Мертвый код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4): у вас значение переменной `num` никак не используется. Смело выкидываем две строки.
3. Если есть строка с бинарным представлением числа, просто берем последний символ, и проверяем, равен ли он строке `"1"` без преобразования символа в целое. Последний символ можно получить по индексу -1 (соответственно, предпоследний - по индексу -2 и т.д). Если у символа два состояния ("1" или "0"), то если символ не равен "1", то он автоматически равен "0", поэтому можно просто использовать `else`, вместо `elseif`.

   ```
   b=int(input())
   b=bin(b)
   g=b[-1]

   if g=="1":
       print ("Yes")
   else:
       print ("No")
   ```
4. Проверить значение младшего бита можно без преобразования числа в строку в бинарном представлении - через битовые операции (см. например [**tproger.ru: О битовых операциях**](https://tproger.ru/translations/bitwise-operations/)):

   ```
   b = int(input())
   if b & 1:
       print ("Yes")
   else:
       print ("No")
   ```